# Elastic search query for filtering on top_hits

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, sense

Assuming, I have a table with following format:

`sdk_index {device_id, serve_count, event_time}`

I want to make an elastic search query which gives me the result of

`1. group by device id and take the max(event_time)`

`2. on the result of 1 check for rows with serve_count > 0 and return the count.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analysis over an aggregation is not allowed. This feature request was closed: [feature request for reducers](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8110)